# Closure lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

I have this kind of function.

```
function SomeFunction()
{

    const int NUMBER_OF_CONCURENT_THREADS = 50;

    List<Guid> sessions = new List<Guid>();

    ManualResetEvent[] doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[NUMBER_OF_CONCURENT_THREADS];

    Action<int> makeServiceCall = (iter) =>
    {
        var proxy = GetProxy();
        sessions.Add(proxy.GetCurrentSessionId());

        doneEvents[iter].Set();
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CONCURENT_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);                

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => 
        {
            int iter = i;
            makeServiceCall(iter);
        });
    }

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);

    Assert.AreEqual(50, sessions.Count);
}
```

The problem is that I am getting `IndexOutOfRangeException` when at `doneEvents[iter].Set();` line of code. Please, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a great article about closing over a loop variable. Check it out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, good ol' closure over the iterator variable ;p

Move the `int iter`:

```
int iter = i;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => {
    makeServiceCall(iter);
});
```

Currently you are capturing something that is changing with the loop, and will usually be **after** the loop by the time the threads kick in. Alternatively, use the arg `o`:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => {
    int iter = (int)o;
    makeServiceCall(iter);
}, i);
```

This passes a boxed copy of `i` at the time the item is queued, so it won't change.

In case the issue isn't clear: variables that are captured into a lambda retain their original declaration point - it is a full lexical closure. The `i` inside `QueueUserWorkItem` is not "the value of `i` at the time this lambda was created", but rather, is "the value of `i` **now**". In most cases, the `for` loop will out-pace thread-creation/pickup by a massive margin, so by the time the threads have started the `for` loop has finished and the value of `i` is now out of bounds for the array.